# placing design.widget.BottomNavigationView to the bottom of a relativelayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have been struggling to place a bottom navigation view to the bottom. It is not positioning to the bottom. The bottom navigation view is placed inside a relative layout with buttons. This is the xml code in the file

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">



    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

above is typical show of my code but the bottom navigation view is not aligning to the bottom. Considering the above snippets, please how can I place the bottom navigation view to the bottom in my activity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `layout_gravity` attribute to `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for your `BottomNavigationView`.

Comment: @blend glad it worked, please accept it as answer for future visitors' reference..

Comment: Didn't think about it ^^ Thank's !

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

to your bottomNavigationView